# Survival model output not consistent with actual data

Tags: survival, cox-model

I am trying to learn Survival modelling using a dummy data. The code is as follows

```
SurvExample <- matrix(0, nrow = 180, ncol = 2)
colnames(SurvExample) <- c("Time", "Event")
for (i in 1:30){
  a = (6*i-5)
  b = (6*i)
  SurvExample[a:b,1] <- i
  for (j in min((6*i-min(5,11-i)),(6*i-max(0,(6-i)))):(6*i-max(0,(6-i)))){
    SurvExample[j,2] <- 1
  }
}
SurvExample[SurvExample[,1]>20,2] <- 0
agg <- aggregate(Event~Time, data = SurvExample, FUN = sum)
fitExample <- coxph(Surv(Time, Event)~., data=as.data.frame(SurvExample))
fitExample2 <- survfit(fitExample)

par(mfrow = c(2,2))
plot(agg[,2]/sum(agg[,2]), type = "l", main = "Observed Death Rate", ylab = "Monthly Death Rate (%)", xlab = "Months", xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(0,0.15))
plot(1-cumsum(agg[,2])/sum(agg[,2]), type = "l", main = "Observed Survival", ylab = "Percent Alive", xlab = "Months", xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(0,1))
plot(-diff(summary(fitExample2)$surv),type = "l", main = "Model Death Rate", ylab = "Monthly Death Rate (%)", xlab = "Months", xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(0,0.15))
plot(summary(fitExample2)$surv, type = "l",main = "Model Survival", ylab = "Percent Alive", xlab = "Months", xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(0,1))
```

However when I compare the the actual distributions vs the model output, I get very different results. For example in the actual monthly death rate peaks at month 6 at 12%. In the model it still peaks at month 6 but is far less than the actual. Similarly the survival curve are also very different. Am I not interpreting the model or the data correctly?

[image]

**EDIT**
Following Theodor's suggestion I made the following changes and the graphs are now comparable in scale. However the survival rates towards the end show a different behavior. Instead of stablizing at 75% after month 20 they go down to 70% after month 20. Is the model smoothing the trend?

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))

# Divide by the number of subjects (180)
plot(agg[,2]/180, type = "l", main = "Observed Death Rate", ylab = "Monthly Death Rate (%)", xlab = "Months", xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(0,0.04))
plot(1-cumsum(agg[,2]/180), type = "l", main = "Observed Survival", ylab = "Percent Alive", xlab = "Months", xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(0.7,1))

plot(-diff(summary(fitExample2)$surv),type = "l", main = "Model Death Rate", ylab = "Monthly Death Rate (%)", xlab = "Months", xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(0,0.04))
plot(summary(fitExample2)$surv, type = "l",main = "Model Survival", ylab = "Percent Alive", xlab = "Months", xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(0.7,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not calculating the Nelson-Aalen estimator correctly. The N.A. estimate of the hazard at time point $t$ is the number of events at $t$ divided by the number of individuals at risk at $t$. You are dividing by the number of remaining events instead.

At each time point, by the way you generated the data, 6 individuals exit the risk set at every time point. Since you have censoring, the estimate of the survival can not be 0 at the end.

You can get the same results as the one from coxph() like this (I did it for the cumulative hazard, but the idea should be clear):

```
agg2  <- aggregate(Event ~ Time, data = SurvExample, FUN = length)
at_risk <- 180 - cumsum(agg2$Event) + agg2$Event[1] 
h0 <- agg$Event / at_risk 
plot(fitExample2, fun = "cumhaz", main = "CumHaz (model)") 
lines(agg$Time, cumsum(h0), type = "s", col = 2)
```

Also, make sure to use the `method = "breslow"` in the argument of `coxph` to make sure you get the same estimate (the default is a more complicated correction for ties).

Comment: thanks for adding to my understanding. I computed death rate and survival not by number of subjects but by number of deaths in the denominator. After making that change the charts become comparable in scale however the curves towards the ends still do not match.

Comment: you have to divide by the number at risk at each specific time point, not by the total number of individuals. At the first time point you have 180 individuals at risk, d1 events, c1 censorings. The estimate is d1/180. At the second time point you have d2 events, and your estimate is d2 / (180 - d1 - c1). The denominator for every time point is in the at_risk vector in the code I wrote.